# Beginner to UNIX Shell scripting and want to know about this code

Tags: unix

I want to understand the following code functionality.

```
if [[ ! -f $LOC_PATH/$MY_PATH ]]
```

here I can understand we are trying to check the existence of a file. But what is `$LOC_PATH/$MY_PATH`. what will be the output of `$LOC_PATH/$MY_PATH` in general.

Comment: `$LOC_PATH` and `$MY_PATH` are two variables containing whatever they have been assigned; there is no way of saying what that would be "in general".

Comment: The script should either declare the variable being set or its an exported variable which you can show with printenv

Answer (score 0):

Basic construct for "if file doesn't exist"

```
#Specify a folder path of importance
$LOC_PATH=/opt/some/folder

#find a specific file conditionally like a date or something
#such as somefile11072016
$MYPATH=$(ls $LOC_PATH | grep "somefile`date +"%m%d%Y")

if [[ ! -f $LOC_PATH/$MY_PATH ]]; then
    #do something if file doesn't exist.
else
    #do something if the file already exists
fi
```